# Disable/enable Codeigniter input field with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following code for input fields:

```
echo form_label('Name :', "first_name[0]");
echo form_input("first_name[0]", set_value("first_name[0]"));
echo form_error("first_name[0]");
```

This outputs the following HTML code:

```
<label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
```

This is part of a form that accommodates 2-5 participants. The idea is to have 2 name fields at least active, while the other 3 are disabled by default and you can activate them with a checkbox. 
I am not very good with JQuery and am unable to accomplish this.
Is it possible with jquery again, to clear any input if the checkbox is selected to activate the field, and then is unchecked after that?

Comment: If you want jQuery help you are better off showing what your dom looks like.

Comment: You are right. My mistake, I've included the output of the code in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe you are looking for something like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wjnxrto/)):

```
<div class="participant">
  <label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
</div>
<div class="participant">
  <label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
</div>
<div class="participant">
  <label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
</div>
<div class="participant">
  <label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
</div>
<div class="participant">
  <label for="first_name[0]"> Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name[0]" value>
</div>
<button id="add-participant">
  Add Another
</button>
```

js

```
$(".participant:gt(1)").addClass("hidden");
$("#add-participant").on("click", function() {
    $(".participant.hidden").first().removeClass("hidden");
  if(!$(".participant.hidden").length) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Only the first 2 will be visible at first, but you can click the button to add more... up to 5.

Or... something like this would probably be better... starting from just a single participant and creating more if needed... with the ability to remove.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wjnxrto/1/)

Comment: EDIT: I ran into a problem - when I press the button to add participant from the first example, my form gets submited. Otherwise works great, thanks!

Comment: Edit2: I fixed the problem with the submission of the form. Now looks like this:
`$(".participant:gt(1)").addClass("hidden");
$(".add-participant").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".participant.hidden").first().removeClass("hidden");
  if(!$(".participant.hidden").length) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});`

Comment: @MihailIvanchev, I thought you were going with the second fiddle

Comment: I am running form validation on all fields, and I rely on being able to manipulate each input field's name. It's easier to do it with the first fiddle, because I just wrap the fields I made in div tags, and hide them. On the second fiddle, I'd have to manipulate the JS code further to be able to change the field name, after each addition or removal. I am also dealing with more than one field that I need to add (it's a group of 6 fields with 6 different names). So I just decided to KIS :)